# I'm a natural in math

Tags: riddle, mathematics, cipher

I'm a natural in math.

The variants of numbers to solve me don't go higher than 100 and 26.

What am I?

```
53
61
23
41
11
```

Comment: Is this a number sequence to be continued, or an unknown object ("I") to be described?

Comment: An unknown object to be described. Thanks for throwing that in :)

Comment: I'm new to this so as a hint; rather think simple than complex.

Comment: I added the "riddle" tag since it's an unknown object to be described - hope you don't mind :-) Welcome to Puzzling SE btw!

Comment: Taking numbers mod 26 and converting to letters gives AIWOK - any use?

Comment: That's not it. See the numbers as separate indexes. Hope that helps, yet not making it too easy :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is

> PRIME

The method for solving is:

> First realise that all the numbers are prime.
>  Convert each prime to the index of the prime, e.g. $53 \to 16$ because $53$ is the 16th prime.
>  You get: $16\;18\;9\;13\;5$
>  Converting this using $a=1,b=2,\ldots,z=26$ you get the solution PRIME.

Comment: Brilliant! And excellent puzzle, @Allendar: very obscure at first sight, but with an answer that's obvious once you see it. +1 to you both.

Comment: Awesome! :D I wasn't sure if my riddle wasn't complex or was serious enough for the level on this site. I hope it was ok :)